# How do I read N lines in a file with Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io

I have a file in the form:

```
3
1 2
3 4
5 7
```

Where the first line is the number of lines

I know that:

```
getInt :: IO Int
getInt = readLn 

main = do num <- getInt
          print (num)
```

Reads the first line.

Next, I tried:

```
readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = fmap (map read.words) getLine
```

For read a line and get a list: [a,b].

And I tried to use the above in a recursive loop

```
loop :: Int -> IO()
loop n = if 1 == n then do num <- readInts 
                           print(num)
        else loop (n-1)
```

I'm getting the first line only:

```
[5,3]
```

But I need to read the rest of lines, given N

Comment: `remainingLines <- replicateM num getLine` gets you a `[String]` for the remaining lines.

Comment: I voted to close as "unclear what you're asking". If you've tried something and it failed, you need to tell us about it. Trying nothing and coming here first... well, that isn't how this site works.

Comment: @DanielWagner And I vote for the community to support me to improve my question... In the place of making empty criticisms

Comment: @Alec thanks, that worked for me. I used `remainingLines <- replicateM num readInts` where: 

`readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = fmap (map read.words) getLine`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of the input file looks a lot like the ones used in programming contests. Here is my standard setup for programming contests like that:

```
import Control.Monad
import Text.Printf

main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- readLn
    forM_ [1 .. n] $ \i -> do
        printf "Case %d: " (i :: Int)
        solve
```

An example of `solve` might be:

```
solve :: IO ()
solve = do
    nums <- map read . words <$> getLine
    print (sum nums)
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is a useful and simple solution! thanks! For iterate over the "list of lists" I modified that, like this:

`readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = fmap (map read.words) getLine

main :: IO ()
main = do num <- readLn
          forM_ [1 .. num] $ \i -> do
              compare <- readInts
              print compare`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to this helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44530009/6243352) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511865/how-do-i-read-n-lines-in-a-file-with-haskell/69815957#comment76017274_44511865), for some challenges you'll need to collect `n` lines and then emit a single result at the end based on an aggregation of the data. An approach for creating a list might use `replicateM` as follows:

```hs
import Control.Monad

toInt :: String -> Int
toInt x = read x :: Int

lineToInts :: String -> [Int]
lineToInts x = map toInt $ words x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- readLn
    remainingLines <- replicateM n getLine
    let list = map lineToInts remainingLines
    print list
```

Sample run:

```
3
0 1
3 4
6 8
[[0,1],[3,4],[6,8]]
```

See also [Read n lines input with Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53131043/read-n-lines-input-with-haskell#53131488)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the function `lines`? It takes a string and returns the same string as a list separated by `\n`. Using this function you don't even have to have the number of lines.