# Read n lines input with Haskell

Tags: loops, haskell, input, getline

I am trying to learn to write Haskell programs. I am failing to read `n` lines input.

The input is

```
n
a b (<----- n times)
```

where `n`, `a`, `b` are numbers.

I tried

```
input = []

readString 0 = return()
readString n =
 do
  z <- getLine
  z:input
  readString (n-1)

main = do
 n <- getLine
 readString n
```

which throws errors. How do I looped read correctly in Haskell?

Comment: What is `z:input` supposed to do?

Comment: @melpomene At a guess: put on your mutable-language-hat and think of it as a typo for `input = z:input`.

Comment: right, that was a typo I didn't notice

Comment: "which throws errors"... what do the errors say specifically, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read N lines in a file with Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511865/how-do-i-read-n-lines-in-a-file-with-haskell)

Comment: thanks for the effort, however the question was asked and answered several years ago and I am not doing any Haskell anymore ;) What I , at the time of asking, didn't know about where the immutables, thus the below answer perfectly explains the issue I struggled with at the time ;)

Comment: @kaiya thanks, but the link is mainly meant for future visitors who might not have your exact same problem and might want to be directed to other resources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haskell is immutable: once you write

```
input = []
```

then `input` is `[]` forever and ever, amen. You could use the same technique you used for having a "changing" value of `n` to have a "changing" value of `input`, that is, pass it as an argument to `readString`:

```
readString 0 input = return input
readString n input = do
  z <- getLine
  readString (n-1) (z:input)
```

If you do this, you will discover that the lines you input get put into `input` starting from the end -- so they come out in reverse order! (If your code snippet had worked, it would also have behaved this way.) One easy fix would be to change the base case:

```
readString 0 input = return (reverse input)
```

A more idiomatic fix would be to do away with the argument entirely, simply returning things in the right order in the first place:

```
readString 0 = return []
readString n = do
  z <- getLine
  zs <- readString (n-1)
  return (z:zs)
```

As you get comfortable with the standard library, you might first graduate to

```
readString 0 = return []
readString n = liftA2 (:) getLine (readString (n-1))
```

and then to skipping the definition of `readString` entirely in favor of rewriting `main`:

```
main = do
  n <- readLn
  lines <- replicateM n getLine
  ...
```